# Is there a place I can take a shower in or near Austin-Bergstrom International Airport?

Tags: airports, hygiene, austin

Are there any places where I can take a shower in or near the Austin-Bergstrom International Airport? If so, how much does it cost?

Comment: AFAIK the two airport lounges don't have showers, but there are a couple of hotels just outside the airport terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Showers are not available at [Austin-Bergstrom International Airport](http://www.austintexas.gov/page/terminals-austin-bergstrom-international-airport), neither in the Barbara Jordan Terminal or in the South Terminal, nor in the two lounges (United and American).

Depending on your plans, the next option would be checking into a hotel and [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/HotelsNear-g30196-qAUS-Austin_Texas.html) lists those nearby the airport, many with free airport shuttle.

Another alternative could be a visit to the YMCA; [TownLake](https://www.austinymca.org/branches/townlake-ymca) is probably closest to the airport, about 15 miles, 25 minutes away, which you could access on a guest pass. See the "Guest Pass" section on [this page](https://www.austinymca.org/programs/join-the-y).